# External hard drive always in use, no apparent reason

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I have used 3 approaches to try and find what's triggering the "Can't stop your drive because it's in use" error message with my new WD external hard drive.

[image: https://imgur.com/a/VnDp9]

LockHunter found nothing

Nothing returns in Resource Monitor or Associated Handles searching for E:\

Nothing returns in Process Explorer searching for E:\

Recycle bin is empty

The only active apps I have open are Chrome, Word, and Excel. I don't have so much as an Explorer window open regarding this drive. This is driving me nuts because I have no choice but to let this hard drive run 24/7 until I get this resolved. Please help! What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED: Thanks to all for the help here and on r/DataHoarder. I wasn't logged into OneDrive and Google Sync wasn't targeted to that drive, but I ended both processes and now my external has been freed. Guess one of those was the culprit!

Answer (score 0):

A couple of likely candidates are:

- Virusscanner, especially the realtime scanner/monitor
- Other anti-malware software running in the background
- Windows Search service
- 3rd party search indexer that is running in the background (including media-player applications that build a "media library" of your movies and songs)
- Backup software configured to make a backup to that disk. I have seen some cases of such software locking the target-disk until the backup is done (which isn't helpful if the backup is scheduled to happen several days in the future).

Some of these, especially the anti-virus/anti-malware, may not show in a normal way because they hook deep in the system.

Anyway, regardless of what is causing it: Shutting the computer down will also stop the blocking software, so you can disconnect the drive safely. There is no need whatsoever to keep it running permanently.

Comment: Thanks for all the info. Only one of those would have been affecting that PC, and it's good to know that shutting down won't cause any harm.